# Count number of instances of C# WPF form application

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to count number of instances of C# WPF default public partial class , i.e Mainwindow class.  I tried using static variable to get the count but the count of static variable is also initialized every time an instance of the class is called.
Below is my code :-

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private static int instances;
    string[] word = { "PRMTCMOU", "POLATP", "RMHTOEBDAOR", "EMSOU", "DEKBYRAO",                              "CEOSPSRO", "YREOMM", "LAERWINEA", "TSRMOFCOI", "TROMINO" };
    int i = 1;
    bool checkStrings = false;
    int score = 0;
    private Socket tcpsocket;
    TcpClient tcpClient;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        instances++;
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += MainWindow_loaded;
        this.Closed += MainWindow_Closed;
        this.Closing += MainWindow_Closing; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you test your theory?

Comment: The static variable will be a different instance only in a new process environment, Do you run this form multiple time from the same process, or from new processes ?

Comment: You cannot solve your problem in the way you have shown. try google shared memory between processes, I saw some C++ wrappers for C# that accomplish it by variable. there are more ways, like reading from file, db, create a process that will host wcf service for counting these instance..

Answer (score 0):

If you truly want to count separate instances (presumably running concurrently), you should start a thread that checks the process list in a loop and modifies your counter to reflect the current count.

Example:

```
void CheckProcessThread()
{
   while (checkProcesses)
   {
      counter = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("MyProc").Length;
      Thread.Sleep(1000);
   }
}
```

Note that I use the "checkProcesses" variable so you can shut down the thread cleanly when you want the program to exit. Also, this function call takes up quite a bit of cpu time, so you may want to increase the thread.sleep in order to keep CPU usage down.

You could also have this function be called on a timer (instead of a looping thread). There are other ways as well, but the basic idea is you need a check for other processes that occurs periodically.